# How to make kendo grid cell blank when field value is zero

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid contains some value coming from database. I want that when I get value of a specific cell value zero then the cell value remains blank. Zero will not be showing in cell

HTML:

```
...
<kendo-grid-column field="studentId" [width]="70" title="Student Id"></kendo-grid-column>
...
```

Expected result:
if value of `studentId` is 0 then the cell will be blank otherwise it will show the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add condition in your column like,

```
<kendo-grid-column field="studentId" [width]="70" title="Student Id">
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
    <div *ngIf="dataItem.studentId == 0"></div>
    <div *ngIf="dataItem.studentId != 0">{{ dataItem.studentId }}</div>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```